# Похожие слова в тексте рядом

Tags: стилистика

Прочитал предыдущий вопрос и задумался: а насколько допустимо употребление в литературном тексте рядом похожих слов? Не обязательно однокоренных, но похожих, как, например: "означать изначально" и т.д.?
Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Похожие слова в литературе могут использоваться в качестве особого художественного приема, который называется фоникой, или звукописью. Звукопись состоит в особом подборе слов, которые своим звучанием способствуют образной передаче мысли.

Например:

Бузина цельный сад залила! Бузина зелена, зелена! Зеленее, чем плесень на чане.Зелена - значит, лето в начале! (М. Цветаева)

Сонные сонмы сомнамбул весны  Сонно манят в осиянные сны. Четко ночами рокочут ручьи. Звучные речи ручья горячи. (И. Северянин)

Звукопись в художественной речи:  http://orfogrammka.ru/OGL04/70648501.html

Answer (score 3):

Очень основательно осветил эту тему  [А.Н. Беззубов](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text16/038.htm#%D0%B7_14) - от несерьёзно-максималистических норм, предлагавшихся братьями Гонкур, Флобером и Мопассаном (не ставить в тексте одинаковых слов ближе чем на расстоянии 400 слов или даже 200 строк друг от друга) до конкретных примеров по лексическим ошибкам, возникающим из-за употребления одинаковых, однокоренных и сходно звучащих слов. Усиленно рекомендую.

Answer (score 0):

Оба ответа полные, ссылка на Беззубова А.Н. очень полезна! Спасибо!